# How to get the Domain name in Python sockets?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, python-3.x

My code:

```
def getHostName(ip_addr):
    host_name = socket.gethostbyaddr(ip_addr)
    if host_name != "":
          return host_name
```

When I plugin `216.58.220.46` as IP value in the above function , it returns the domain name as : `maa03s19-in-f14.1e100.net` instead of `google.com` . So what socket method should I use to get the usual Domain Name

Comment: `host 216.58.220.46` returns `maa03s19-in-f14.1e100.net` that is the correct (dns) hostname. `host google.com` gives me `173.194.112.69` (and others).

Comment: "1e100.net" is also owned by google (in the traditional meaning, one google == 10**100)

Comment: Okay , not only google but also this weird name comes for many websites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a guaranteed single name for an IP address, the internet doesn't work like that.

You can't do it in Python sockets - because you can't do it at all, because "*the* domain name" isn't a concept that exists. Many domain names can resolve to one IP address, and the reverse lookup entry in DNS for an IP address doesn't have to have any relation to them.

e.g. `maa03s19-in-f14.1e100.net` *is* a valid name for that IP address, just not one you recognise.

It's a question that doesn't make sense with how DNS and IP addressing work.